# Backbone.js master-detail view, navigation issue (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm struggling to get a simple master-detail scenario working with Backbone. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn7bG/4/) and code is below.

Problem 1: this navigation doesn't work at all if I switch "pushstate" to true. What I really want is to have no hashes/pound signs in my urls.

Problem 2: my users might rock up on a url like /accommodation/287, not always on the home page. How would you deal with that using the router?

Thanks a lot for any help!

```
var AccommodationItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        html: "",
        loaded: false
    },
    urlRoot: "/Home/Accommodation/"
});

var AccommodationItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template("<a href='#accommodation/<%= id %>'><%= description %></a>"),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var AccommodationList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: AccommodationItem
});

var DetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () { },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get("html"));
    },
    setModel: function (model) {
        this.model = model;
        var $this = this;
        if (!this.model.get("loaded")) {
            /*
            this.model.fetch({ success: function () {
                $this.model.set("loaded", true);
                $this.render();
            }
            });*/
            $this.model.set("html", "<h2>Full item " + this.model.get("id") + "</h2>");
    $this.model.set("loaded", true);
    $this.render();

        } else {
            $this.render();
        }
    }
});

var AccommodationListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.addAll();
    },
    addOne: function (item) {
        var itemView = new AccommodationItemView({ model: item });
        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function () {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    }
});

var App = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "accommodation/:id": "show"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.detailView = new DetailView({ model: new AccommodationItem({ id: 1 }) });
        $("#detail").append(this.detailView.el);
        this.accommodationList = new AccommodationList();
        this.accommodationListView = new AccommodationListView({ collection: this.accommodationList });
        $("#app").append(this.accommodationListView.el);
    },
    start: function () {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false });
    },
    index: function () {
        this.fetchCollections();
    },
    show: function (id) {
        var model = this.accommodationList.get(id);
        this.detailView.setModel(model);
    },
    fetchCollections: function () {
        var items = [{ id: 1, description: "item one" }, { id: 2, description: "item two" }, { id: 3, description: "item three" }];
        this.accommodationList.reset(items);
    }
}));
$(function () {
    App.start();
});
```

**EDIT:** In a comment below I mentioned the Codeschool backbone.js tutorial. Just want to say that I have now finished BOTH parts of the course and it DOES cover exactly the AppView pattern described in the accepted answer. It's an excellent course and I thoroughly recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a few of the concepts mixed up.

There is too much to explain here, so I've (very roughly) put together a patch of your code that works as you intend. I would advise that you put it side-by-side with your own and see what I have done differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtxK8/2

A couple of things, you should not init Backbone.history from within a router. your 'init' should look something more like this

```
      $(function () {
        window.app = new App();
        window.appView = new AppView({el:document});
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
      });
```

This is setting a 'wrapper' view than encompasses the entire page. Also, you have far too much logic in your router. Try to only use the router for routes. After my quick re factor, your router only contains this:

```
      var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "": "index",
          "accommodation/:id": "show"
        },
        show: function (id) {
          var model = window.appView.accommodationList.get(id);
          window.appView.detailView.setModel(model);
        }
      });
```

The `AppView` (that I have written for you now does all of that initialize work.

```
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(){
          this.detailView = new DetailView({ model: new AccommodationItem({ id: 1 }) });
          $("#detail").append(this.detailView.el);
          this.accommodationList = new AccommodationList();
          this.accommodationListView = new AccommodationListView({ collection: this.accommodationList });
          $("#app").append(this.accommodationListView.el);
          this.fetchCollections();
        },
        fetchCollections: function () {
          var items = [
            { id: 1, description: "item one" },
            { id: 2, description: "item two" },
            { id: 3, description: "item three" }
          ];
          this.accommodationList.reset(items);
        }
      });
```

Even after my re factor, it's still far from optimal, but I have provided it all to help you on your journey of learning :)

I would then recommend you follow some of the on-line tutorials step-by-step so that you can set up the structure of your app in a better way.

Good Luck, and be sure to check out http://jsfiddle.net/wtxK8/2 to see it working.

**EDIT:** I have not address your second question. there is enough to be worked on with question 1 to keep you busy. If I have more time later, I will help further.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm still digesting that. I've done a number of backbone tutorials (peepcode, tekpub and codeschool) and they're all different. The code in the original snippet was closely based on the first backbone course at codeschool.com. I haven't done the second one yet so maybe that introduces the method you've used here.

Comment: is that definitely the right version of the fiddle? It doesn't look like the same code you quote above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shane. I've incorporated your version into my actual application and it's working a treat! Regarding question two, I'm using asp.net mvc - so I'm pretty sure the first thing I have to do is map an MVC route to /application/id otherwise the user will get a 404. Not sure how to then tell backbone to show the detail view. Anyway, thanks a million.